# Three.js: How to Rotate Equirectangular Panorama Texture

Tags: three.js, glsl, textures, mesh, panoramas

I have 2 textures inside a single mesh that represent 2 equirectangular panoramic images. I need to rotate one of 2 textures in a desirable position using supplied coordinates. In other words, the position of one texture needs to be modified (shifted/offset) before I display it. I cannot rotate the mesh, because it holds 2 textures where only needs to be adjusted.

Here are my fragment shaders:

```
uniform samplerCube tCube0;uniform samplerCube tCube1;uniform vec3 tCubePosition0;uniform vec3 tCubePosition1;uniform float scale0;uniform float scale1;uniform float tFlip;uniform float opacity;uniform float mixAlpha;varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
#include <common>
void main() {
    vec3 vWorldPositionScaled0 = mix(vWorldPosition, tCubePosition0, scale0);
    vWorldPositionScaled0.x *= -1.0;
    
    vec3 vWorldPositionScaled1 = mix(vWorldPosition, tCubePosition1, scale1);
    vWorldPositionScaled1.x *= -1.0;
    
    vec4 tex0, tex1;
    tex0 = textureCube(tCube0, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPositionScaled0.x, vWorldPositionScaled0.yz ));
    tex1 = textureCube(tCube1, vec3( tFlip * vWorldPositionScaled1.x, vWorldPositionScaled1.yz ));
    
    gl_FragColor = mix(tex1, tex0, mixAlpha);
}
```

I thought to add the offset to my `uniforms`

```
offset0: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
```

and adjust shaders:

```
    vec3 texCoord0 = vec3(tFlip * vWorldPositionScaled0.x, vWorldPositionScaled0.yz) + vec3(offset0, 0.0);
    tex0 = textureCube(tCube0, texCoord0);
```

but that produces wrong results. How can I shift/offset/rotate the texture by supplying offset coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equirectangular environment maps are not supported natively in `three.js`. Before they are processed in the shader, they are internally converted to the cube map format.

Cube maps are normally sampled like so in `three.js`:

```
vec4 envColor = textureCube( envMap, vec3( flipEnvMap * reflectVec.x, reflectVec.yz ) );
```

- `envMap` represents the cube map sampler.
- `flipEnvMap` controls whether px/nx should flipped since cube render targets are rendered differently than cube map textures.
- `reflectVec` is the reflection vector which controls the sampling.

When you want to *rotate* the sampling of a cube map, you need this:

```
vec4 texColor = textureCube( envMap, reflectionMatrix * vec3( flipEnvMap * vWorldDirection.x, vWorldDirection.yz ) );
```

The `reflectionMatrix` transforms the reflection vector and is 3x3 matrix uniform. You ideally compute it from an Euler object in your JS code.

Hopefully, `THREE.WebGLRenderer` will support this feature at some point: see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16328.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Mugen87. I suspect however that it would be easier to have 2 meshes that can be rotated with one texture inside, than one mesh with 2 textures that get rotated. It's hard to prove this without POC but that is what I am leaning towards. I wonder if anyone can advise.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and nearly got it to work. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2yjsp8h/) is getting Y offset as expected in `applyOffset` function, but X is spinning clockwise instead of left/right. I am stuck and unable to resolve for a while.